# Windows Cmd: What to type to run a program with your input file?

Tags: java, windows, compiler-errors, command

so i have an input file that i would like to test out with this program... the file name is "sample.txt.asc" how do i run this input file in this program? i thought the order would go:

1)javac project1.java  2)java project1< sample.txt.asc

but it is giving me an error saying array index out of bounds... at line 5. sorry any help would be great! thanks

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
public class project1 {
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException {
    Scanner inFile = new Scanner( new File( args[1] ) );
    String[] cypherLines;

    outputHeaderLines( inFile );
    cypherLines = getCypherLines( inFile );
    outputObscureLines( process( args[0], getDataArrayFrom( cypherLines ) ), cypherLines );
    outputRestOfLines( inFile );
    inFile.close();
    }

    public static void outputRestOfLines( Scanner F ) {
    while ( F.hasNext() )
        System.out.println( F.nextLine() );
    }

    public static void outputObscureLines( char[][] data, String[] lines ) {
    // Print data chars and then rest of chars from lines
    for ( int row = 0; row < data.length; row++ ) {
        for ( int col = 0; col< data.length; col++ ) {
        System.out.print( data[ row ][ col ] );
        }
        for ( int col = data.length; col < lines[ row ].length(); col++ ) {
        System.out.print( lines[ row ].charAt( col ) );
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    // Now output that "extra" line we remembered
    System.out.println( lines[ lines.length - 1 ] );
    }

    public static char[][] process( String command, char[][] dataArray ) {
    char[][] newDataArray = duplicate( dataArray );

    for ( int i = 0; i < command.length(); i++ ) {
        switch ( command.charAt( i ) ) {
        case 'v':
        case 'V':
        newDataArray = flipVertical( newDataArray ); break;
        case 'h':
        case 'H':
        newDataArray = flipHorizontal( newDataArray ); break;
        case 'r':
        case 'R':
        newDataArray = rotate( newDataArray ); break;
        default:
        // this should be an error, but we'll presume the
        // command sequence is valid and do nothing.
        }
    }
    return newDataArray;
    }

    public static char[][] rotate( char[][] data ) {
    char[][] temp = new char[ data.length ][ data.length ];

    for ( int row = 0; row < data.length; row++ )
        for ( int col = 0; col < data.length; col++ )
        temp[ data.length - col - 1 ][ row ] = data[ row ][ col ];
    return temp;
    }

    public static char[][] flipHorizontal( char[][] data ) {
    char[][] temp = new char[ data.length ][ data.length ];

    for ( int col = 0; col < data.length; col++ ) 
        for ( int row = 0; row < data.length; row++ )
        temp[ row ][ data.length - col - 1 ] = data[ row ][ col ];
    return temp;
    }

    public static char[][] flipVertical( char[][] data ) {
    char[][] temp = new char[ data.length ][ data.length ];

    for ( int row = 0; row < data.length; row++ ) 
        for ( int col = 0; col < data.length; col++ )
        temp[ data.length - row - 1 ][ col ] = data[ row ][ col ];
    return temp;
    }

    public static char[][] duplicate( char[][] data ) {
    char[][] temp = new char[ data.length ][ data.length ];

    for ( int row = 0; row < data.length; row++ )
        for ( int col = 0; col < data[ row ].length; col++ )
        temp[ row ][ col ] = data[ row ][ col ];
    return temp;
    }

    public static char[][] getDataArrayFrom( String[] lines ) {
    char[][] data = new char[ lines.length - 1 ][ lines.length - 1 ];

    // Only process valid cypher lines
    for ( int row = 0; row < lines.length - 1; row++ ) 
        for ( int col = 0; col < lines.length - 1; col++ )
        data[ row ][ col ] = lines[ row ].charAt( col );
    return data;
    }

    public static String[] getCypherLines( Scanner F ) {
    String[] lines = new String[0];
    String currentLine = F.nextLine();

    while ( ( currentLine.length() == 64 ) && 
        ( lines.length <= 64 ) &&
        noEqualSigns( currentLine ) ) {
        lines = push( lines, currentLine );
        currentLine = F.nextLine();
    }
    // I have a current line of cypher text I need to preserve.
    return push( lines, currentLine );
    }

    public static void outputHeaderLines( Scanner F ) {
    String currentLine = "";

    do {
        currentLine = F.nextLine();
        System.out.println( currentLine );
    } while ( ! blank( currentLine ) );
    System.out.println();
    }

    public static String[] push( String[] list, String item ) {
    String[] newList = new String[ list.length + 1];

    for ( int i = 0; i < list.length; i++ )
        newList[ i ] = list[ i ];
    newList[ list.length ] = item;
    return newList;
    }

    public static boolean noEqualSigns( String line ) {
    // If they exist, they'll be at the end, so just check the
    // last char 
    return line.charAt( line.length() - 1 ) != '=';
    }

    public static boolean blank( String line ) {
    for ( int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++ )
        if ( ( line.charAt( i ) != ' ' ) &&
         ( line.charAt( i ) != (char)9 ) )
        return false;
    return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you mean for the < to be part of the arguments? If so try making it so it's something like: javac project1.java filename.txt \<

Comment: If you do that, you'll need to change the order of arguments in your code.

Answer (score -1):

For ex:
I have an jar (export as jar) file (program.jar) as program and in.txt file as input file.
I will run:

> java -jar program.jar in.txt
>   
>   With javac, you should use javac javaclass.java in.txt

Notice without **"<"** letter.

And in program code, I should use **args[0]** as input file name instead of **args[1]**.
Hope it will help.
I just mention to command line, I didn't read you code.